# What will (or did) end of mission look like for the MarCo cubesats?

Tags: end-of-life, marco-cubesats

These two 6U's are the farthest cubsats from Earth.

Are they still talking to us and being talked to?

With loss of [remaining propellant for momentum unloading needed for high-gain antenna pointing](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/26773/12102) do they become incommunicado?

What will (or did) end of mission (or end of life) look like for the MarCo cubesats?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mission for MarCO A and B was to perform a relay of communications for the Insight lander, which lowered the latency of data during landing, and that mission was a success. The mission ended on November 26, 2018 and JPL lost contact with them on January 4, 2019. [Source](https://solarsystem.nasa.gov/missions/mars-cube-one/in-depth/)

> MarCO A and B successfully completed their missions on Nov. 26, 2018. WALL-E was last heard from on Dec. 29, 2018; EVE on Jan. 4, 2019.

According to [this](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32332/31577) answer the Cubesats weren't going to be in orbit so they would have continue out into deep space. The JPL team said they would continue to monitor them over the next couple weeks after the landing of Insight to see how the relay performed and how much fuel is on board. [source](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7295)

JPL said the reason for the loss of communication with WALL-E was that it had a leaking thruster which made it wobble and made it hard to communicate with, and for both they mention the issue linked to the light sensor which helped it point its solar arrays at the sun.

Currently they are in orbit around the sun drifting slowly apart. When they last received communications from them they were about a million miles apart(WALL-E was 1 million miles from Mars and EVE was 2 million miles from Mars). [source](https://www.jpl.nasa.gov/news/news.php?feature=7327) This kinda got a little dark but the mission was a success and JPL says there will be more of these deep space cubesat missions.