# Major topic headings for lunar CubeSat mission design planning?

Tags: orbital-mechanics, the-moon, spacecraft, cubesat, mission-design

I am working on a project to design a complete mission for a lunar CubeSat.

Assuming that the launch segment is already covered and I need to focus on the spacecraft design.

I wanted to know what are the main questions should I answer during the initial design. The questions I have come up with so far are

1. How do we communicate with the satellite?
2. Actuators and sensors typically used for attitude maneuvers?
3. Choosing the right orbit

I wanted to know what are the main topics I need to keep in mind during the design? Just like section headings that I need to fill up.

Also, are there any good sources online that I can follow specifically for lunar mission design?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Although this is an interesting question, asking for "an extensive list" means that's pretty broad. From the help center: "If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much." Can you [edit] your question and narrow the focus to something with a more limited scope?

Comment: You are right. What I meant by that is I just need section headings so I can build my own extensive list. Fixed it!

Comment: Good edit, hopefully that is narrow enough now. Thanks for responding.

Comment: By "launch segment" I am guessing that you mean that something else will get the cubesat all the way to an orbit around the Moon? Or will it be deployed in Earth orbit and then use solar-electric propulsion to get to the Moon and insert itself into an orbit as these discuss: [Could a cubesat be self propelled to the moon from LEO?](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/34772/12102) and also [Going from LEO to lunar using only low-thrust ion propulsion - can it be done?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/28037/12102)

Comment: By launch segment, I mean I assumed that the trajectory from ground until orbit insertion has been designed already. The CubeSat will be deployed in a lunar orbit and will not go there from earth.